# Estimating counts from sampled data

Tags: estimation, variance, sampling, expected-value

I am working on counting events from sampled web logs. To formalize the problem, consider a random process in which we randomly record an event with known probability $r$. Say we have $n$ recorded events. I think, the distribution over the true number of events $N$, given the sampling rate and the number of recorded events is:
$$
P(N | r, n) = \begin{cases}
0, &{\rm if}\ N\ \text{less than}\ n  \\
{N \choose n} r^n (1-r)^{N-r}, &{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I would like to:

1. find a closed form expression for the expectation
2. find a closed form expression for the variance

I'm sure this is a common stats problem, but I am having trouble finding a reference and I'm rusty on working with infinite series.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), so you can just use the known formulas for mean and variance. Note that the standard form of the distribution counts only the number of un-logged events, so we need to modify them slightly to get the total number of events N. Using your notation,
$$
E[N] = \frac{(1-r)n}{r} + n = \frac{n}{r}
$$

$$
Var[N] = \frac{(1-r)n}{r^2}
$$

The expectation is intuitive - if you log 5% of the events, then the real number of events should be 20x larger. The variance is not so obvious, but you can see that as you record more events (r gets closer to 1) the variance gets smaller.