# Determining actual number of observations in a dataset

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation

I have two datasets one is a dataset with doctors in which I have the procedures they have performed at a given hospital where the actual number of procedures is not captured by this data since it is a sample. Let's call this dataset-1

I also have another dataset which contains the actual number of procedures for the hospitals in the first dataset. Let's call this dataset-2.

Here is an example:
Say Dr. A has performed 250 units of procedure x at hospital-1 and hospital one has a total of 1000 units of procedure x for 2012 this information is in dataset-1.

Now in dataset-2 we find that hospital-1 actually had a total of 2000 units of procedure x for 2012.

My question is:
1) What methods can I use to find/estimate the actual number of units of procedure x performed by Dr. A?

Right now my thought was take the ratio of the sample so 250/1000 = .25 and multiply that by 2000 which would say that we estimate that Dr. A actually performed 500 units of procedure x for 2012.

Problems in my mind immediately arise though. I don't believe this ratio would hold in the larger space. It is very possible that Dr. A performed 251 units of procedure x or on the extreme 1900 of them.

I should note that there are of course multiple doctors in dataset-1 so I also thought about using confidence intervals.

Any help or comments would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are the data in dataset 1 sampled from the set of all procedures? If they are sampled uniformly at random (e.g. every procedure has an equal chance of being included in dataset 1) then you can estimate the true number of procedures by performing the linear scaling you proposed. If you also want a measure of uncertainty in that estimate, you can use the negative binomial distribution [as I described in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/estimating-counts-from-sampled-data/134106#134106).

If procedures are sampled non-randomly (e.g. some doctors are most likely to have procedures in dataset 1) then there is very little you can do without explicitly modeling this in some way.